# Как связать методы, чтобы после выполнения первого круга процесс не заканчивался?

Tags: java, методы

Задача (вкратце) : задается буква англ. алфавита и при помощи ascii кода надо переделать Прописную в строчную и наоборот, код заканчивается после нажатия указанного символа (он вводится с клавиатуры).

Моя проблема: у меня 3 метода:

1. Отвечает за условие (совпадение и не совпадение с символом "конца")
2. за изменение символа
3. за вывод результата.

Не понимаю, как их связать, чтобы после выполнения первого круга процесс не заканчивался.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("What is the 'end' symbol?");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        char endSymbol = in.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Put your symbol in");
        char newSymbol = in.next().charAt(0);
        ConsoleChanger consoleChanger = new ConsoleChanger(endSymbol);
        while(){
        consoleChanger.continueProcess(newSymbol);
        consoleChanger.endProcess();
    }}
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public class ConsoleChanger {

    char endSymbol;
    char sysIn;
    char resultSymbol;

    ConsoleChanger(char c) {
        endSymbol = c;
    }

     void startProcess(char sysInSymbolA){
       sysIn = sysInSymbolA;
       if (sysIn == endSymbol){
           System.out.println("It is the end...");
           System.exit(0);
                }
     }

     void continueProcess(char sysInSymbolB){
         sysInSymbolB = sysIn;
         int number = (int) sysIn;
        if (number>= 65 && number<= 90){
            number += 32;
            resultSymbol = (char) number;
        }
        else{
            if (number>= 97 && number <= 122){
                number -=32;
                resultSymbol = (char) number;
            }

        }
     }

     void endProcess(){
        System.out.println(resultSymbol);
     }

}
```

Comment: В этом фрагменте кода проблема не с методами, а с тем, что чтение символов с консоли происходит вне цикла `while`, а также с тем, что метод `startProcess` не используется.

Comment: спасибо, постараюсь найти ошибку.

Answer (score -1):

Представленный вами код не самый оптимальный, но если нужно чтобы он заработал, то вот следующие необходимые исправление в методе main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("What is the 'end' symbol?");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    char endSymbol = in.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Put your symbol in");
    char newSymbol = in.next().charAt(0);
    ConsoleChanger consoleChanger = new ConsoleChanger(endSymbol);
    while(true){
        consoleChanger.startProcess(newSymbol);
        consoleChanger.continueProcess(newSymbol);
        consoleChanger.endProcess();
        System.out.println("Put your symbol in");
        newSymbol = in.next().charAt(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: ``while(true)``?

Comment: @Qwertiy там по хорошему надо бы условие выхода прописать, но у автора вопроса конкретное требование: "Моя проблема: у меня 3 метода ...
Не понимаю, как их связать, чтобы после выполнения первого круга процесс не заканчивался" , а один из этих методов как раз и отвечает за выход, но он void а не boolean, его нельзя в условие поместить. В общем, автор вопроса хотел связать методы, чтобы работало - я сделал строго по тз. Не понимаю за что мой ответ минусят.